# Chrome & Safari setInterval working slow (1Hz & 2Hz) on Active Tab

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, animation, safari, setinterval

> **Goal:** creating animation updated at 100Hz.

My animation updates the background-position property. Current background-position is calculated by a function that is supposed to fire 100 Times per second to create an illusion of smooth movement.

> **Problem:** animation is not smooth in Chrome and Safari.

It behaves as if "updated background-position" function was fired only once per second in Chrome and only twice per second in Safari.

> **Additional information:**

- my code works fine in Firefox 4 / Internet Explorer 8 and higher / Opera 11.10
  (didn't test previous versions)
- I am using *setInterval*( **function()** { //do stuff here } , 10 ) to update my animation
- I am aware how Chrome handles JS in inactive tabs - the problem occurs on **active tab**
- I am using jQuery 1.7

I am sure there's gotta be a way to create smooth animations in Safari/Chrome. Please help.

> **Edit:** I cannot use .animate() because I am tracking mouse movement and calculating current background position depending on where mouse points. For that I have to check mouse position every 10 milliseconds (and I **must** use setInterval for it).

Answer (score 2):

Because you wan't to animate, and you are using jQuery, why do you put a setInterval at 10MS? While jQuery has an `.animate` function which will handle the animations? And this function has a [Interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/) setting, where you can put the FPS.

```
$(element).animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 -250px)"}, 
        {duration:500})
    })
```

More information about background animations: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

Comment: I don't see how jQuery's .animate() might help. I am setting the current background position with .css(). If Chrome & Safari execute JS only at 1Hz/2Hz it does not matter wheather I use setInterval or .animate (which is a jQuery function that has to use setTimeout or setInterval anyways).